# What is the reason behind the output?

Tags: python-3.x, output

**Input**:

```
x, y = 20, 60
y, x, y = x, y-10, x+10
print(x, y)
```

**Output**:

```
50 30
```

> *What I expected*?

- x = 20
- y = 60
- y = x = 20
- x = y - 10 = 20 - 10 = 10
- y = x + 10 = 20

**Expected output**:

```
10 20
```

Why Isn't this the case? Is it because the expressions are evaluated first then the variable are assigned the value?

Comment: If it was _so_ sequential, statements like `x, y = y, x` would equalize variables rather than swap them.

Answer (score 7):

The right side is evaulated COMPLETELY before the left. Then the left hand side is evaluated left to right.

```
x, y = 20, 60
# x = 20, y = 60

# ----------------------

y, x, y = x, y-10, x+10
# Evaulate the right first:
# x, y-10, x+10 = 20, 50, 30
# So now we have
# y, x, y = 20, 50, 30

# Now it goes left to right so:
# y = 20
# x = 50
# y = 30 --> note this overwrote the first y assignment

print(x, y)
```

Thus

```
50 30
```

Comment: I always find it easier to think of the right side (`x, y` or `y, x, y` or `a, b, c`) is an unnamed tuple

Comment: @error-syntactical-remorse I'd leave as it was. If to elaborate tuples I'll put on both sides to make it very clear. Does that make sense?